# Cannot suppress warnings that are executed during an import call

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, warnings, suppress-warnings

I'm unable to filter warnings in Python when they're emitted as part of an import. I've tested the following with Python3.8.

This works:

File A:

```
import warnings

def old_func():
    warnings.warn("This is an old function.")
    pass
```

File B:

```
import warnings
from file_a import old_func

warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
old_func()
```

The warning message is suppressed as expected. But if I change File A like this:

```
import warnings

def old_func():
    warnings.warn("This is an old function.")
    pass

old_func()
```

It stops working. I assumed that was because I wasn't setting the filter before the import so I changed File B as follows:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
from file_a import old_func
old_func()
```

And still no dice. The warning is emitted no matter what I do. I've also tried the catch_warnings() context manager as follows:

```
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    from file_a import old_func
    old_func()
```

The warning is still emitted. If the warning is emitted during an import there seems to be no way of ignoring it.

I've done some hacky things like temporarily making stderr and stdout in-memory file-like-objects temporarily and that works but it's terrible. I'd like to find a way to do this with reasonable machinery.

Since this is for a command line tool with an entry-point created with setuptools, it's quite a pain to package it in a way that adds a -W option to the interpreter for end users.

A side update: I've confirmed this works on Python 3.6 and does not work on Python 3.8.

Comment: Maybe cuz you're trying to use the `simplefilter` function but launching 2 warning instances meaning your not actually changing the settings from the first instance but only for the second one. To fix this you could suppress it in the first file or just import a function in the first file that runs the suppress code. I don't know if this would work since I didn't test but if it works let me know so I can write a proper answer.

Comment: @DeadSec since in my real-work use, "File B" is an upstream library, I cannot so simply change it's behavior. Still, warnings should be possible to suppress with the warnings filters. On further inspection it seems that my code works fine on Python3.6 but not 3.8. Weirdness.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the minimal reproducible examples !

I followed your examples, running them each time. But I did not observe the same thing than you :

```py
# file: a.py
import warnings

def old_func():
    warnings.warn("This is an old function.")
    pass

old_func()
```

```py
# file: b.py
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
from a import old_func
old_func()
```

does not emit the warning for me, on Windows CPython `3.6.8`. Can you check again ?

> I assumed that was because I wasn't setting the filter before the import so I changed File B as follows
> looks very reasonable to me

The last version of your A file works too (i.e. the warning is not displayed)

Comment: I didn't have Python 3.6 anymore (turns out I had symlinked python3.6 to the python3.8 binary for anything that expected 3.6 on my path) so I recompiled it myself from scratch. Lo and behold... No warning emitted. 

As soon as I run it on Python 3.8 - the warnings are no longer suppressed. I'm guessing that means this is a bug in Python itself; some regression introduced between 3.6 and 3.8.

I couldn't find any bug report on the Python issue tracker around this but I suppose my search-foo might not be up to snuff. I guess I could try bisecting till I find the offending commit.

Comment: @user1411616 no warning on CPython `3.8.2` on Ubuntu. no warning on CPython `3.8.5` on [www.online-python.com](https://www.online-python.com/)

Comment: Very weird; I'm able to reproduce this quite easily simply by switching interpreters. I am on 3.8.10  - I'll try compiling 3.8.5 and see if the issue still occurs there. Thanks for checking that out!